# Removing Strange Google Analytics Code From Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

Client wants me to add Google Analytics to her site.

I get into her Google account, copy-paste the code into the appropriate slot on the Wordpress plugin.

It doesn't work. Google says they're picking up a different tracking code.

Right clicked her site's main page. Went to "View Source". There's an unfamiliar Google Analytics tracking code in there. We've deduced that the former webmaster put it in and set it up with an account she lost the information for.

It occurs higher up in the head than the other code, so that's the only one Google is picking up.

It's not from a plugin. I pull up some Google Analytics on Wordpress guides to figure out the most common locations it could be hiding. Check the theme; not in the theme. Check the functions, header, etc-- everywhere I can find that her former webmaster could've put it. Checked Firebug. Still no luck finding the source.

Used Wordpress "String Locator" plugin to try to find where this is coming from; used the UA# of the abberant tracking code. Doesn't come up with anything. Tried again with generic Google Analytics code. All it comes up with is the plugin I installed to put the new Google Analytics code in.

Any ideas how I can go about fixing this?

1) Is there something else I can do to find where it's coming from?

Or a way to make the new Google Analytics code work without removing the other one?

2a) Is there some way to force the new code higher up in the head than the other one?

2b) I know you can add multiple Google Analytics codes to a page if you give one a name-- for instance:

ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'auto');

ga('create', 'UA-22222222-2', 'auto', 'myTracker');

But would that still work if the two trackers are created by two completely different scripts?

3) Forgive my limited understanding of web development, but: would it be feasible to use a PHP str_replace to change the abberant tracking code into the new one?

Thank you in advance for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

GA code can be placed within site via **Wordpress Plugins** , adding code in **header.php** and using hook in **functions.php**. And you found no codes within themes neither in plugins.

Is there any relevant plugins other than your's installed within theme related to analytics?